# Незакрываемое WPF приложение

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, .net-core

Есть задача, сделать приложение для компьютерного клуба, которое запускается на игровых компьютерах на весь экран и если он не оплачен, посетитель не может никак закрыть программу. Разработка ведется на WPF, думал получится сделать что-то с помощью user32, но пока никаких успехов. Буду безмерно благодарен за любую идею

Comment: Обратите внимание на реализацию служб на С# и вероятно клиент-серверного приложения

Comment: Да, основная логика будет в службе, wpf приложение нужно, чтобы перекрыть экран и не дать пользователю взаимодействовать с компьютером, если у него закончилось оплаченное время

Comment: а можно просто запускать скринсейвер и запаролить его. Теперь система будет защищать нас.

Comment: (не проплаченная реклама) имел опыт работы с комплексом [astalaViSta](http://www.astalavista.ru/), очень хороший, правда это было лет 10 назад, но сайт еще работает. Быть может проще взять готовое? А вообще такие штуки делаются подменой Winlogon сервиса. Способ не простой, но надежный и если я ничего не перепутал - единственный гарантированно рабочий.

Comment: Еще костыльный вариант - сделать беззаголовочное окно, развернуть его на весь экран, дать ему TopMost=true (поверх всех окон) и зарегать комбинацию клавиш Alt+Tab чтобы система не смогла на нее реагировать либо отрубить мышь+клаву как устройства. Минус такого решения - есть в диспетчере задач процесс, который можно убить и окно просто не выскочит когда закончится время. Такой способ использовался лет 15 назад в компьютерных клубах Ростелекома. Еще вариант, научиться разлогинивать юзера удаленно. Закочилось время - делать логаут из системы (или лочить станцию). Началось время - логин.